# How to solve error Android\sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:958

Tags: android

I have create a HelloWorld project in netbeans of android ...
i am getting error when debugging the project please explain me where the error occure

Here the images:
[image]
[image]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. This is a Q/A site for specific programming questions. Asking for code or for recommendations of things is off-topic. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to find out more about this. Making an [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of what you have already tried is an appreciated concept.

Comment: Any particular reason why you want to use NetBeans instead of Android Studio?

Comment: Netbeans was never officialy supported for Android development, you can use old tools for Eclipse or using the currently IDE that is Android Studio